# What I need to sign jar file?

Tags: java, security, jar, jnlp

My colleague gave me a Java project for supporting and enhancement. I need to sign `.jar` file. I found only next files: `genkey.bat`, `project.cer`, `signjar.bat` and `keystore-jar.jar` inside project, 
no more information. But from tutorials I undertand that I need alias, passwords etc... May be it is real to sign jar with this existing files (not to create new keystore etc)?

Comment: I had tried that once, so I followed the steps as described [here](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/signJARfiles.txt)

Comment: *"..need to sign `.jar` file"*  Why? Specifically what extended privileges does it require?

Comment: @AndrewThompson for example, until we not sign `logback` library we get exception when we try to log using it's `error()` method. It's ugly to sign third-party libs, but we cant do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
javac ClassName.java
jar cvf JarName.jar ClassName.class
keytool -genkey -validity 3650 -keystore myKeyStore -alias mykeyName
keytool -selfcert -keystore myKeyStore -alias mykeyName -validity 3650
jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore AppletClass.jar mykeyName
```